# How do I set my python command prompt to interactive mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, interactive-mode

I'm starting out with Python, I have installed the command prompt and IDLE. Version 3.7, 32 bits. I am having trouble setting Python to interactive mode.

I have tried changing the environmental variable, through the following steps:

Going to PC → Advanced System Settings → Environmental variable → new

Then typing:

Variable Name: `Python`

Variable Value: `C:\Python37`

Just so you know it is saved in my desktop folder, in `python 3.7` folder, and in that is the command prompt and IDLE (type is said to be shortcut)

SO when I go to the command prompt and type `python` or `Python` or `Python37` or `Python3.7`, it just shows a name error/not defined error

The thing is I can still use it to print and calculate stuff, but setting it to interactive mode is the challenge. I am very new as you can tell, help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that you are able to run python someScript.py from your commandline, but not start python in interactive mode by just typing python?

Comment: I'm confused. To my understanding, a command prompt by definition is in "interactive mode".

Comment: "I can still use it to print and calculate stuff" - you can use *what* to print and calculate stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you installed python using the downloaded file *python-3.7.0b1.exe*. If so, you have two different "command prompts":

In your start menu you should find a *Python 3.7* folder and inside this folder an entry *Python 3.7*. If you click on that entry, you get a "command prompt" window named *Python 3.7*. **Now you already are in interactive mode.**

If, on the other hand, you have a standard Windows command prompt window, you first have to call

> python

inside this window to get the above-mentioned Python window (provided your python executable is on your path).